# Docker Selenium chromedriver can't run more than 51 containers through VPN

Tags: selenium, docker, selenium-chromedriver, vpn

> ```
>                    container ... linked through --net=container:VPNContainer 
>                               -> Container 1 (runing chrome)
>                               -> Container 2 (runing chrome)
>     SYSTEM -> VPNContainer    -> Container 3 (runing chrome)
>                               -> Container 4 (runing chrome)
>                               -> Container ... (runing chrome)
>                               -> Container 52 (running chrome)
> ```

i have a docker image that opens chrome via python-> selenium -> chromedriver 
as soon i run 51 docker containers through my vpn container i get

```
Message: unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist,
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.9.93-linuxkit-aufs x86_64)
```

---

**How to reproduce error:**

create docker image that opens chrome
run that docker image through a vpn container image via

```
--net=container:yourvpncontainer
```

run more than 51 container through **yourvpncontainer**
on container 52 you get the error.

[vpn container](https://github.com/haugene/docker-transmission-openvpn)

---

**How to Solve this issue, and why does this error accour?**

every docker container has its own chromedriver and runs in itself, so there is no selenium hub or ect just the docker image that has all in itself so why do i get a port error, im just using the vpn via the net command as my network? and how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching your containers manually in the VPN, then it is an incomplete implementation of docker. The better way to utilize docker here is through **docker-compose** file.

```
selenium-hub:
  image: selenium/hub
  ports:
  - 4444:4444

chrome:
  image: selenium/node-chrome
  links:
  - selenium-hub:hub
  environment:
    HUB_HOST: hub
  volumes:
  - /dev/shm:/dev/shm 

firefox:
  image: selenium/node-firefox
  environment:
    HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR: hub
  links:
  - selenium-hub:hub
```

All you got to do is run `docker-compose up -d`  in the directory containing this yml file and it shall spawn a hub with 1 chrome and 1 firefox node. The console log is detached and if you want to see that too , just omit the `-d` switch in this command.

Now , In order to scale up , open a new terminal in the same directory containing this file and run `docker-compose scale chrome=5 firefox=5` and BOOM! your total FF nodes are 5 and total Chrome nodes are 5.

Run `docker ps`  and see all the running containers status right away.

Comment: 1. your code does not work im running a mac, /dev/shm:/dev/shm only works on linux
2. im not asking how to run a selenium grid, but okay if thats the better way..
-> still you didnt answered how to run the grid through a vpn, do i have to link every node? or just the hub?
->i tried it out with the correct docker-compose code, and i can't run 100 nodes and running 100 tests simulataniosly something still miss

Comment: There is an upper limit after which your hardware gets overloaded. If you are not on linux , then omit the volumes key.  How many stable nodes were you able to host on your mac machine.

Comment: its not a hardware problem im running it in a scalable cloud.
the problem is i can't use selenium grid, its not scalable as i want.
So i have to use it the way im using it now, the only problem is that i can only attach 51 containers to the vpn container, so i have for 100 containers create 2 vpn containers. i don't want that.  is there a dummy container that only forwards? that i use 1 dummy container that connecting to all, and that dummy container connects to the vpn?

Comment: Just to let you know, even on scalable clouds. There is a quota system to restrict certain resources in a network such number of firewall rules, number of requests allowed per day, etc. Just refer to the subscription limit document of your cloud provider.

Comment: everything is working like i want the only problem is that running more containers than 50 i need to create a new vpn image, and thats my problem i don't want to have 2 vpn images running for 100 instances

Comment: Try Zalenium. It might do the job you want to do.